# helaili/jekyll-action does not update the browser with gh-pages branch content

Tags: ruby, github-actions, jekyll, github-pages

I built [my personal site](https://erap129.github.io/) using Jekyll ([repository](https://github.com/erap129/erap129.github.io)).

I created a plugin to retrieve information from my Medium account and populate my site's "Blog Posts" page, this is the [plugin](https://github.com/erap129/erap129.github.io/blob/master/_plugins/jekyll-display-medium-posts-json.rb). This plugin creates a collection called `medium_posts_json` which I iterate over in my blog posts page.

I am also using the [Jekyll Actions](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/jekyll-actions) GitHub action because the vanilla GitHub pages do not support custom plugins. In order to use this action I added a workflow file [here](https://github.com/erap129/erap129.github.io/blob/master/.github/workflows/github-pages.yml).

This GitHub action pushes the built site into a branch called `gh-pages`, and when I look at the [page with the generated Blog Posts](https://github.com/erap129/erap129.github.io/blob/c27043401cc2235b414ce3be54e8e19f5e373595/blogposts/index.html#L197) it contains all expected entries and that my plugin worked successfully (the list in the Blog Posts page is populated using the plugin I created).

The problem is that this is not the page presented on the live site! In my live site, [the Blog Posts page](https://erap129.github.io/blogposts/) is empty, this means that the HTML file in my `gh-pages` branch is not the same as the live one.

Why is that? Isn't GitHub supposed to host the content of the branch I specified? How do I even start debugging this? When I build the website locally and upload the static contents using `.nojekyll` it works just fine, but I wanted to use the GitHub action to automate this process, so I won't have to rebuild manually every time I post on Medium.

Thanks.

Comment: The master branch contains the source files for the build. The `gh-pages` branch contains the build artifacts (the static site files) and is generated automatically by GitHub Actions. That's why I'm not really sure I understand what you did :) The site should work as-is after I run the action because I want to be able to run it automatically every X days. And indeed, the `gh-pages` content seems fine to me, it's just that it doesn't appear in the browser (for the blog posts page).

Comment: I have deleted my previous comment. I was confused because of the paths for the CSS. I have read a bit, see my answer. Interesting challenge, read a lot about the new way of deploying pages with actions. Found old SO posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72079903/do-i-need-the-pages-build-deployment-github-action-when-i-have-another-action-f) that confused me.

Comment: I think the missing link, as you described, was setting the "built-from" setting in Github to `gh-pages`. Thanks for all the effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GitHub will not host the content from the branch when you do not deploy it.

The GitHub action you use ( https://github.com/helaili/jekyll-action) is triggered when a commit is pushed to master but it only

- builds the site.
- copies the _site content to the target branch (`gh-pages`).

Because your workflow is only triggered on commit, you need to set up something to run the build every x day, e.g. a [runner](https://jasonet.co/posts/scheduled-actions/).

I have [forked your repo](https://github.com/cadamini/erap129.github.io) and set up the action as you did:

```
name: Build and deploy Jekyll site to GitHub Pages

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master 

jobs:
  github-pages:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - uses: actions/cache@v2
        with:
          path: vendor/bundle
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-gems-${{ hashFiles('**/Gemfile') }}
          restore-keys: |
            ${{ runner.os }}-gems-
      - uses: helaili/jekyll-action@2.4.0    # Choose any one of the Jekyll Actions
        with:                                # Some relative inputs of your action
          token: ${{ secrets.JEKYLL_PAT }}
          target_branch: 'gh-pages'
        env:
          JEKYLL_PAT: ${{ secrets.JEKYLL_PAT }}
```

To get it running, I have used the default GitHub pages deployment action to deploy the page, as you can see here: https://cadamini.github.io/erap129.github.io/ (follow the link on the index to see the blog posts).

In GitHub, I have configured that the site is built from the `gh-pages` branch (root folder):

---

[image]

---